# Python Muti-line cmd entries in one environment

Tags: windows, batch-file, python-3.x, cmd, command-prompt

I am trying to make a real .bat to .exe converter. I'm currently attempting to create a script witch injects cmd-commands into one cmd-process/environment. Here is what I have so fare:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from os import system as cmd
def ce(*a):
    a = list(a)
    for b in range(0, len(a)):
        cmd(a[b])
        # I need each entry of cmd(a[b]) to run in the same cmd environment and therefore
        # do what a normal .bat/.cmd program would.
    return a
cd1 = ['@echo off', 'set hw=Hi', 'echo %hw%', 'set hw', 'pause']
if ce(*cd1) != cd1:
    print('Error')
    cmd('pause')
quit()
```

All it does is iterate through those commands in 'cd1' and executes them one-by-one. As soon as I establish 'hw' as 'Hi', the variable is gone. Not only that but instead of saying "ECHO is off' it displays "%hw%". IF anyone can help me, please do so.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you execute each line in a new cmd environment instead of executing line by line in one cmd. To get it workig you have to concatenate all lines with `&&` and then run the whole string as one command line.

But there's still a problem. Concider this line:

`@echo off && set x=123 && echo %x% && pause`

This will not return the output 123 because the commands are executed at once so `echo %x%` won't know that `%x%` is set to 123. To get this working you have to add the command `SETLOCAL  EnableDelayedExpansion` and adress the value of `x` by `!x!` instead of `%x%`.

So the line

`@SETLOCAL  EnableDelayedExpansion && @echo off && set x=123 && echo !x! && pause`

will give you the desired output.

You should decide how you want your script to work. If you use `a && b` b will only be executed if a was successful. If you user `a & b` instead b will be executed even if there was an error in a.

Comment: That was an example list of commands. The purpuse of my project is to be able to run any .bat executable without putting the commands in a real .bat file because then people can see the batch code.

Comment: @AidanCodeX: you just have to take any bat file, concatenate all lines with &&, replace any %x% by !x! and put "@SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion" at the start of the line. Then just execute the whole line. This will work with any bat file.

Comment: That didn't work. I tried: b = '@echo off\n:a\ncls\necho Hello World!\npause\ngoto a\n'.replace('\\n', '&&'), then os.system(b), it closed and returned 1.

Comment: Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion doesn't work on the command line, but you can use cmd.exe /v:on